# How to get area name in WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have written a filter for `Webapi` action methods.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
      //Log area name here by calling the helper method.
    var areaNam = Helpers.GetAreaName(actionContext);
}
```

I thought to retrieving area name by writing a nice helper method.

```
 public static string GetAreaName(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext httpContext)
 {
     var areaName = string.Empty;
     var routeData = httpContext.ControllerContext.RouteData;
     if (routeData != null)
     {
         areaName = routeData.Route.DataTokens["area"] as string;
     }

     return areaName;
 }
```

But `areaName` is always null or empty.

Can any one shed some thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You want `Values` not `DataTokens`.

```
public static string GetAreaName(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext httpContext)
{
    var areaName = string.Empty;
    var routeData = httpContext.ControllerContext.RouteData;
    if (routeData != null)
    {
        areaName = routeData.Route.Values["area"] as string;
    }
    return areaName;
}
```

[Documentation - RouteData.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.values(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets a collection of URL parameter values and default values for the route.

Comment: `Route` doesn't contain a definition for `Values`. **routeData.Route.Values["area"]** throws error.

Comment: Have use added `using System.Web.Routing`